# maskedtextbox alignment

Tags: vb.net, textbox, maskedtextbox

I am working on a VB.Net Windows application. I am trying to use **MaskedTextBox**. My mask is `999999`, `RightToLeft` is `true`, `TextAlign` is `right`. It is not letting me enter characters from the right. It is entering them from the left. When I type 1234 and save I get `1234____` when I expect to get `____1234`.

Please tell me what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. The code is in the Form's load event.

```
MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "999999"
MaskedTextBox1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes
MaskedTextBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
```

Comment: I found that setting TextAlign to Left (the default) instead of Right got the desired behavior of right-aligning the text within the user control boundaries (i.e. `[    __1234]` instead of `[__1234    ]`).

Comment: Also, note that this makes left/right arrows on the keyboard move the input caret the "wrong" direction.